# How to set unix time stamp in Apache 2.4 cookie?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to set Unix Timestamp in cookie. Is there any expression variable available in Apache 2.4 to get it?

Something like `RewriteRule .* - [CO=time:%{UNIX_TIMESTAMP}:.example.com:0:/]`

Answer (score -1):

You can use mod-rewrite `%{TIME}` variable

```
RewriteRule .* - [CO=time:%{TIME}:.example.com:0:/]
```

Comment: That just returns the normal UTC time stamp `20211208061427`